# Get argument names from a parser, without parsing arguments in argparse python

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following argument parser in a python script `make_parser.py` :

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Multiplies the input <n> by <m>'
)
parser.add_argument(
    'n', type=float, help='Input number to be multiplied'
)

parser.add_argument(
    '-m', '--optional-multiplier',
    type=float, default=1,
    help='multiplier for <n> : (default: 1)'
)
```

How do I get the positional and optional argument names and their details, possibly as some object, or just as a dict.

For e.g., some method like `parser.get_positional_args`

```py
>>> from make_parser import parser
>>> parser.get_positional_args()
<argparse.ArgumentClass object at 0x7f3871721e80>
```

And the same for optional arguments, something like `parser.get_optional_args`

Comment: Maybe use `_get_positional_kwargs()` and `_get_optional_kwargs()` methods?

Comment: @SamChats I don't think it returns the previously defined arguments. It has a required argument ```dest```.

Comment: `parse._actions` is a list of the defined `Actions`.  Each action has a `dest` attribute.  Positionals are identified by the an empty `option_strings` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your code:

```
for action in parser._actions:
    print(action)

print([(action.dest, action.option_strings) for action in parser._actions])

print([action.dest for action in parser._actions if not action.option_strings])
print([action.dest for action in parser._actions if action.option_strings])
```

result (edited for clarity):

```
0848:~/mypy$ python3 stack57450629.py 
_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None)
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='n', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=<class 'float'>, choices=None, help='Input number to be multiplied', metavar=None)
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-m', '--optional-multiplier'], dest='optional_multiplier', nargs=None, const=None, default=1, type=<class 'float'>, choices=None, help='multiplier for <n> : (default: 1)', metavar=None)

[('help', ['-h', '--help']), ('n', []), ('optional_multiplier', ['-m', '--optional-multiplier'])]

['n']

['help', 'optional_multiplier']
```